# HTML radio showing output on newPage from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a school project involving a bill for a hotel after inputing all the information. I want `newPage` under `function displayBill()` in the javascript to show "Discount: $20" only when the bug discount is checked as yes on the html form. When someone chooses the no option on the form, the javascript function should say `bugDiscount = 0`, however, I don't want discount to show up on the new page(bill summary). I know that it shows up because when the `displayBill()` function is called it always shows the discount. Should I make 2 different `displayBill()`'s, 1 with the discount and 1 without? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Here's the html code:

```
<form>
    Guest ID Number: <input type="text" id="custID" /><br />
    Room Type: 
    <select id="roomType" />
        <option></option>
        <option>Double</option>
        <option>Single</option>
        <option>Parlor</option>
    </select><br />
    Length of Stay: <input type="text" id="stayLength" name="numOranges" /><br />
    Number of Drinks: <input type="text" id="drinkNum" name="numOranges" /><br />
    Number of Towels: <input type="text" id="towelNum" name="numOranges" /><br />
    Number of Flushes: <input type="text" id="flushNum" name="numOranges" /><br />
    Bug Complaints?: <br /> <label>
        <input type="radio" name="bugComplaint" value="Yes" onclick="getCheckedRadio(this)" />Yes<br />
        <input type="radio" name="bugComplaint" value="No" onclick="getCheckedRadio(this)" />No<br />
        <br />
    Customer Comments: <br />
    <textarea name="customerComment" cols="50" rows="5">Enter your comments here...</textarea> <br />
    <br />

    <input type="button" onclick="calculateFinalBill()" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
const doublePrice = 150;
const singlePrice = 100;
const parlorPrice = 80;
const drinkPrice = 5;
const towelPrice = 3;
const flushPrice = 1;

var custID;
var roomPrice;
var stayLength;
var drinkNum;
var towelNum;
var flushNum;
var totalDue;
var subtotal;
var roomType;
var bugDiscount;

function calculateFinalBill() {
validateForm();
    if(roomType == "Double"){
    roomPrice = doublePrice;
    }

    if(roomType == "Single"){
    roomPrice = singlePrice;
    }

    if(roomType == "Parlor"){
    roomPrice = parlorPrice;
    }

    roomTotal = roomPrice * stayLength

    towelTotal = towelPrice * towelNum

    flushTotal = flushPrice * flushNum

    drinkTotal = drinkPrice * drinkNum

    subtotal = roomTotal + towelTotal + flushTotal + drinkTotal

    totalDue = subtotal - bugDiscount

    displayBill();
}

function getCheckedRadio(which){
var bugValue = which.value;
    if (bugValue == "No"){
    bugDiscount = 0;
    }
    if (bugValue == "Yes"){
    bugDiscount = 20;
    }
}

function validateForm(){
custID = parseInt(document.getElementById("custID").value);
if(isNaN(custID)){
    alert('Customer ID must be a number');
    return;
}
if(custID <= 0){
    alert('Customer ID must be greater than zero');
    return;
}

roomType = document.getElementById("roomType").value;
if(roomType == ""){
    alert("Room type must be selected");
    return;
}

stayLength = parseInt(document.getElementById("stayLength").value);
if(isNaN(stayLength)){
    alert('Length of Stay must be a number');
    }
if(stayLength < 0){
    alert('Length of Stay must be greater than zero');
    return;
}

drinkNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("drinkNum").value);
if(isNaN(drinkNum)){
    alert('Number of Drinks must be a number');
    }
if(drinkNum < 0 || drinkNum > 25){
    alert('Number of Drinks must be 0-25');
    return;
}

towelNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("towelNum").value);
if(isNaN(towelNum)){
    alert('Number of Towels must be a number');
    }
if(towelNum < 0){
    alert('Number of Towels must be zero or greater');
    return;
}

flushNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("flushNum").value);
if(isNaN(flushNum)){
    alert('Number of Flushes must be a number');
    }
if(flushNum < 0){
    alert('Number of Flushes must be zero or greater');
    return;
}

customerComment = document.getElementById("customerComment");
}

function displayBill(){
var newPage =  "<html><head><title>Billing Summary</title></head>"; //Add CSS after title
    newPage += "<body><h1>Happy Hoppin Hotel</h1>";
    newPage += "<h2>Guest Billing Summary</h2>";
    newPage += "Guest Identification: " + custID;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Room Type: " + roomType;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Length of Stay: " + stayLength;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Room Charge: $" + roomTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Drink Charge: $" + drinkTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Towel Charge: $" + towelTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Flushing Charge: $" + flushTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Subtotal: $" + subtotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Discount: $" + bugDiscount;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Total Due: $" + totalDue;
    newPage += "<br />";

var j = window.open('','','width=400,height=500');
j.document.write(newPage);
j.document.close();
}
```

This is what the new page(bill summary) should look like when there is a bug discount https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3334.jpg

This is what it should look like if there isn't a bug discount https://i.stack.imgur.com/w95UU.jpg

If my question is confusing, then please specify what I need to clarify. I was having trouble thinking about how to ask this question without making it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is indeed quite unclear, as it is also unclear why you do all this in javascript. Anyway, what you could do is test the bugDiscount value :

```
function displayBill(){
var newPage =  "<html><head><title>Billing Summary</title></head>"; //Add CSS after title
    newPage += "<body><h1>Happy Hoppin Hotel</h1>";
    newPage += "<h2>Guest Billing Summary</h2>";
    newPage += "Guest Identification: " + custID;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Room Type: " + roomType;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Length of Stay: " + stayLength;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Room Charge: $" + roomTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Drink Charge: $" + drinkTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Towel Charge: $" + towelTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Flushing Charge: $" + flushTotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    newPage += "Subtotal: $" + subtotal;
    newPage += "<br />";
    if(bugdiscount != 0)
    {
        newPage += "Discount: $" + bugDiscount;
        newPage += "<br />";
    }
    newPage += "Total Due: $" + totalDue;
    newPage += "<br />";

var j = window.open('','','width=400,height=500');
j.document.write(newPage);
j.document.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't want discount to show when there is no discount needed so I would need the opposite of that somehow. I just cant figure out how to negate the Discount line for the new page.

Comment: have you at least tried this ? It won't show the discount unless bugdiscount is different than 0... it seems to be exactly what you're looking for... Anyway if you need the exact opposite then just change "!=" to "==" in the condition and that's it...

Comment: Sorry i'm very new to javascript. I thought it ment something else but you're right. I'll mess with it and see if I can get it to work then accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put that and how does it know where that line goes in the newPage stuff?

Comment: I've updated my code example, taking back your whole displayBill function and inserting the needed test where it should be. Hope this helps